# ansible - rebuild database output so it can be used as a dict to lookup a value

Tags: ansible, jinja2

i query a database with two search strings (with with_items), and register that in a variable. i print the variable with debug and get something like this:

```
{
 "result": [
  {
      "documentId": "653",
      "value": "Ubuntu"
  }
 ]
},
{
 "result": [
  {
    "documentId": "652",
    "value": "OracleLinux"
  }
 ]
}
```

then, i want to write an experession to lookup the value of the documentId,
depending on the field 'value' above, ie. depending on the operating system.

in other words, is it possible to write an ansible expression, when, at the current server, if {{ ansible_distribution}} is 'OracleLinux' it gives me "652" ?

or is there some way to accomplish this, ie. by doing some set_fact first...i tried that but failed, because i tried to set_fact in a with_items loop, but only the first one got set.

Comment: as a workaround i just made a dict which has to be manually synced with the database, which looks like this: osys_dict:
  OracleLinux: 652
  Ubuntu: 653

Answer (score 1):

If original dict is `res`, then:

```
{{ (res | map(attribute='result') | selectattr('value','equalto', ansible_distribution) | first).documentId }}
```

Comment: the force is very strong with this one